ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC Ajax, passing null into controller
I am trying to submit data into a controller method, in order to add the item to a repo.
I am doing this from a HTML (razor) page using AJAX jQuery.
The form serialises the data, and can read the elements. However, as that data is sent to the method, the argument passed into the method is null.
I have gone through a number of posts here on stackoverflow and the internet.
I originally had the controller function as returning an IActionResult and an Action result. Returning the View(); however, the argument was still null.
I have tried to have the argument be the object itself, that being (Book book) such is the model. But to no avail.
The form is serialized and will display in the console:
"ISBN=9780132350884&Title=gg&Author=gg&AvailabilityStatus=true&AvailabilityStatus=false"
I am clearly missing something here.
Thanks in advance.
.cshtml / jQuery:
@model Library.Models.Book

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "BookAddView";
}

<h1>BookAddView</h1>

<h4>Book</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form id="frm_newBook">
            <div class="mb-3 form-group">
                <label asp-for="ISBN" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ISBN" class="form-control" id="input_isbn"/>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" id="input_title" />
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 form-group">
                <label asp-for="Author" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Author" class="form-control" id="input_author" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check mb-3">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="AvailabilityStatus" id="input_avail" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AvailabilityStatus)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button id="btn_SubmitBook" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btn_SubmitBook').click(
        function () {

            var data = $("#frm_newBook").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("BookAdd", "Library")',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: data
            });
        }
    );
</script>

C# controller:
// POST : Book/Create and AddBook
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult BookAdd(string jsonInput)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonInput))
    {
        return Json(0);
    };

    Book book = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Book>(jsonInput);

    _bookRepository.AddBook(book);
    return Json(1);
}


Basically, you are trying to submit a form and the data you are  trying to post is not JSON. Therefore we couldn't send it in JSON format. About why the argument is null, that's because even we set the content type to JSON, it will still be application/x-www-form-urlencoded, then we have to use FromForm in the controller. So that I'm afraid that use [FromForm] Book book instead of string jsonInput will solve the issue too.

You are using .net 8 MVC and you are trying to submit form data, by the way, you already use taghelpers e.g. asp-for, so that using form submitting might be the first option in my humble. This require us to add post action for the form <form id="frm_newBook" asp-action="BookAdd" asp-controller="Comment"> and change the post method like below. This is form submit, so that we need to use FromForm
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult BookAdd([FromForm] Book book) {
    return Ok("success");
}


From submit will make the whole page refresh and this might be the reason that you are trying to use ajax. You can then use Michal's code, var data = $("#frm_newBook").serialize(); makes the form data to be form string but not Json string. Or you might use this ajax and still use my Post method. I test it in my side which worked well.
$("#btn_SubmitBook").click(function(e) {
    var data = $("#frm_newBook").serialize();
    console.info(data);
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://localhost:7064/comment/BookAdd',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data
    });
});

Even if we set Content type to "application/json; charset=utf-8" in ajax, it will still be application/x-www-form-urlencoded in the request, so that we have to use FromForm in controller method.


This worked, i did get an issue with having a paramatered constructor on the Book class. But, that was quickly solved, by having another paramaterless constructor for this. Thank you.

Value that you have posted:

ISBN=9780132350884&Title=gg&Author=gg&AvailabilityStatus=true&AvailabilityStatus=false

does not seem like a valid JSON and I guess that could be the case.
Also your C# method does not specify from where to take the jsonInput parameter value. Try adding FromBody attribute to the parameter:
public JsonResult BookAdd([FromBody] string jsonInput)

In order to verify value that is sent to the backend, go to browser's devtools and see in Netowrk tab if what values are being sent in the request:

I can suggest something, that produces correct JSON, if that's the case:
var data = new FormData($("#frm_newBook"))
var json = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(data))

$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("BookAdd", "Library")',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: json
});

